# Listからnp.arrayによる変換について

Tags: python, python3, array, numpy

numpy.arrayからなるListの、numpy.arrayへの変換について質問です。

下記の行列(test)があります。

```
test = 
[array([4.76175243, 5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935,
        6.82693267, 6.68472261, 5.93395087]),
 array([5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267,
        6.68472261, 5.93395087, 5.73621779]),
 array([5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267, 6.68472261,
        5.93395087, 5.73621779, 5.22481018])]
```

np.array(test)を行って、下記アウトプット. 1の配列（3, 8）を期待しているのですが、
アウトプット.2(3, )となってしまいます。
何が原因なのでしょうか？

アウトプット.1

```
[array([[4.76175243, 5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935,
        6.82693267, 6.68472261, 5.93395087]),
 [5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267,
        6.68472261, 5.93395087, 5.73621779]),
 [5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267, 6.68472261,
        5.93395087, 5.73621779, 5.22481018]])
```

アウトプット.2

```
array([array([4.76175243, 5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935,
       6.82693267, 6.68472261, 5.93395087]),
       array([5.35280132, 5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267,
       6.68472261, 5.93395087, 5.73621779]),
       array([5.6358859 , 6.23928513, 6.75275935, 6.82693267, 6.68472261,
       5.93395087, 5.73621779, 5.22481018])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.array` は「Python の生のリストを NumPy array に変換する」ものなので、「NumPy array のリスト」を変換すると「NumPy array の NumPy array」になります。

NumPy array のリストを 2 次元の NumPy array に変換したい場合、[`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) が使えます。

```
>>> test = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
...         np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
...         np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])]
>>> arr = np.stack(test)
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

pythonは、まだ始めたばかりなので、正確な事は書けませんが、、、

> アウトプット.1 
>   こちらは、そもそも カッコ()の組み合わせが一致していません。

また、定義のコードを見ると、結果的には、 (3,8) の配列かも知れませんが、形式はジャグ配列になっているので、 "アウトプット.2" になるのは当然と思いますが、どうでしょうか?

追記、 上記の例は、配列の配列。従って 単純な2次元配列とはちょっと違います。